# Warning about config property after migrated to Quarkus 2.8.0

Tags: quarkus

I have migrated an extension from `quarkus 2.7.5` to `quarkus 2.8.0`.

After the migration, I run `mvn clean install` and the console shows me weird warnings about all (maybe 100) config properties (some of them are defined by me, other not like java.specification.version):

`[WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "my.property" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo`

I think my integration-tests module causes this issue.
Here is my class in runtime folder:

```java
import java.util.Optional;

import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.ConfigItem;
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.ConfigPhase;
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.ConfigRoot;

@ConfigRoot(phase = ConfigPhase.RUN_TIME, prefix="", name = "myApp")
public class MyAppConfig {
   
    @ConfigItem(defaultValue = "defaultValue")
    String firstProperty;

    @ConfigItem(defaultValue = "")
    Optional<String> secondProperty;

    @ConfigItem(defaultValue = "defaultValue")
    String thirdProperty;

    // Getters ...

    
}
```

Here is my test:

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;

@QuarkusTest
public class MyAppIntegrationTest {

    @ConfigProperty(name="myApp.first-property")
    String firstProperty;

    @ConfigProperty(name="myApp.second-property")
    String secondProperty;

    @ConfigProperty(name="myApp.third-property")
    String thirdProperty;

    @Test
    public void testConfig() {
        assertEquals("firstValue", firstProperty);
        assertEquals("secondValue", secondProperty);
        assertEquals("thirdValue", thirdProperty);
    }

   
}
```

Can someone help me on this ? For instance, do I need a BuildItem for that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you defining your properties?

Comment: In a `resources/application.properties` file. But some warning logs concern properties that I did not even define (example: java.specification.version, os.version, sun.io.unicode.encoding)

Comment: Does the same problem occur if you clean the environment?

Comment: Yeah, the problem occurs even if I clean the environment. It appears only if I make a `mvn clean install`. It does not occur when I run my app in dev mode (with `mvn compile quarkus:dev`)

Comment: Do you have a sample I can try?

Comment: After some investigation this pm, I think the warnings are caused by: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/23943.

Comment: @geoand I edited my original post to focus on the root cause. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours on those warnings, I found that they was caused by the empty prefix field of the `ConfigRoot` annotation.

Setting name field to `""` and prefix to `"myApp"` fixed the issue